# Handling Redirection after successful login using Firebase in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement a login feature in my React application using Firebase authentication. I am able to successfully authenticate users with their email and password, but I am unable to properly handle redirecting the user to the home page once they are logged in.

Here is my login form component:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';

const LoginForm = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const firebase = useFirebase();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        firebase.login({
            email,
            password
        })
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password" />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

How can I handle redirecting the user to the home page after a successful login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using React Router Dom You can use Redirect from React Router Dom
onc you authenticate user.
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect

ie:

```
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";
 firebase.login({
            email,
            password
        }).then(()=> redirect("/homeppage"));
  }
```